# How can I delete rows that have 2 characters or less in a particular column?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I'm cleansing a database table so that I can build a data warehouse for my coursework, however first I need to make sure that the data is of a quality.

There are a lot of name entries have only a single letter. I want to delete those rows with a single script.

[image: Some of the name entries]

Comment: Oracle REGEX should work for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the number of chars in the column `name` with the function [length()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions076.htm)

```
delete from tablename
where length(trim(name)) < 2
```

The function [trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rreftrimfunc.html) could also be useful in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
Delete from @your_table
Where length(@your_name_column)=1
```

This will remove all the rows with a 1 character length name

Answer (score 1):

This has not been tested but REGEXP_LIKE can be very usefull for things like this.

```
delete from your_table 
where  regexp_like (column, '[A-Z]|[a-z]')
```